# perl issuing os command with defined variables

Tags: perl, unix, kerberos

I am adding functionality into my scripts so that they can use kerberos authentication to run automatically and use secure protocols when executing. I have my functionality working for shell scripts that do exactly what i want, however i am having issues porting it to perl to work within my perl scripts as i am new to perl. Here is my working shell code and trying to get the same functionality in perl:

```
#!/bin/sh
ticketFileName=`basename $0-$$` #set filename variable to name of script plus the PID
krb5CacheLocation=/tmp/$ticketFileName #set ticket cache location to /tmp + script name
/usr/share/centrifydc/kerberos/bin/kinit -c $krb5CacheLocation -kt /root/.ssh/someaccount.keytab someaccount #get TGT and specifiy ticket cache location on kinit
export KRB5CCNAME=$krb5CacheLocation #set the KRB5CCNAME variable to tell ssh where to look
```

What i have attempted in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $ticketFileName = `basename $0-$$`;
my $krb5CacheLocation = '/tmp/'.$ticketFileName;
`export KRB5CCNAME=$krb5CacheLocation`;
`/usr/share/centrifydc/kerberos/bin/kinit -c $krb5CacheLocation -kt /root/.ssh/someaccount.keytab someaccount`;
```

Seems it is not liking the passed variable that i am referencing in the OS command. Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You aren't executing the commands in the same order.

Comment: What makes you think that Perl thinks of `$0` and `$$` as shell variables?

Comment: Btw, you should probably describe your problem a bit better than "it is not liking". `use strict; use warnings;`, do debug print statements, you tell us what goes wrong.

Comment: @TLP because it will be issuing that command on a unix shell (hence the backticks) which will return the script name and pid and store it in the ticketFileName perl var

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yeah i added them in the wrong order but i tested both and it does not matter which executes first.

Comment: @VinnieBiros but Perl can interpolate variables into shell commands, which is what TLP was getting at. It doesn't know you want a unix environment variable, it is local for a Perl variable called that.

Comment: @VinnieBiros What Hunter said is what I was aiming at. You seem to realize that your ridiculously long variable name `$krb5CacheLocation` is interpolated, but seem to forget that the same applies to any string with a dollar sign in front of it. In this case, the variables mean the same thing, but the implementation of `$0` varies somewhat. So like I said, do a debug print of your file name to make sure it is what you think. And use strict and warnings.

Comment: Why convert at all, when your conversion doesn't do much more than wrap your shell code in backticks?

Comment: @innaM That's the best point in this debate so far. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The, or *a* problem is that you establish `KRB5CCNAME` as an environment variable in a shell that's immediately thrown away.  michael has one alternative to this.  You could also pass the environment variable on the `kinit` invocation, with this syntax:

```
`KRB5CCNAME=$krb5CacheLocation /usr/share/centrifydc/kerberos/bin/kinit etc.`
```

Although as you throw away the output, just use `system` or, if this is also the last thing you'll be doing, `exec`:

```
exec "KRB5CCNAME=$krb5CacheLocation /usr/share/centrifydc/kerberos/bin/kinit etc."
```

A benefit of `%ENV` manipulation is that you can then use multi-argument `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

   # what is the value of $0 , which script? a: set to current script
   my $ticketFileName = `basename $0`;
   chomp($ticketFileName);
   $ticketFileName .= $$;
   my $krb5CacheLocation = '/tmp/'.$ticketFileName;
   $ENV{'KRB5CCNAME'}=$krb5CacheLocation;
   @x = qx(/usr/share/centrifydc/kerberos/bin/kinit -c $krb5CacheLocation -kt                    
     /root/.ssh/unixmap0000.keytab unixmap0000);
   print join "\n",@x,"\n";
```

Comment: say the script is named script.pl , it would set the ticketFileName var to /tmp/script-6875 for example

Comment: @TLP That is incorrect. basename strips the extension. right out of man page:
root# man basename
BASENAME(1)                      User Commands                     BASENAME(1)

NAME
       basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames
EXAMPLES
       basename /usr/bin/sort
              Output "sort".

       basename include/stdio.h .h
              Output "stdio".

so basename of $0 would be just the filename

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
use File::Basename;

# set filename variable to name of script plus the PID
my $ticket_file_name = basename "$0" . "-$$";

# set ticket cache location to /tmp + script name
my $krb5CacheLocation = "/tmp/$ticket_file_name";

# set the KRB5CCNAME variable to tell ssh where to look
$ENV{KRB5CCNAME} = $krb5CacheLocation;

# get TGT and specifiy ticket cache location on kinit
system( "/usr/share/centrifydc/kerberos/bin/kinit -c $krb5CacheLocation -kt /root/.ssh/someaccount.keytab someaccount" );
```